# Singular or Plural matching?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, british-english, grammatical-number

Often I hear things like ' The crowd were noisy', which I feel is wrong - a crowd is a singular entity. What about 'The Commonwealth games *is* /*are* starting soon'?

Comment: Is this British English, or what? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: British English for this question!

Answer (score 1):

> *The crowd **were** noisy*
>
> *The crowd **was** noisy*

Both are fine. This is just an issue of dialectal. In British English, *a collective noun* is often treated as a plural entity. But in American English, it's singular.

---

> The Commonwealth game**s** *is/**are*** starting soon.

In this case, *are* should be used because it's plural.

Comment: Except that the 'Commonwealth Games' could be construed as one thing, or several.

Comment: @Tim It's plural noun because you **don't capitalized** the *Game*. It could be considered as a singular noun if it were capitalized.

Comment: So Commonwealth Games is singular, whereas Commonwealth games is plural?

Comment: @Tim it could be, it depends on the context.

Comment: So that narrows it down to a 50/50, where we started.